# Each different solution of $y''+{\sin xy'+e^{-x}y=0}$ has different min and max points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, wronskian

if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two linear independent solution of $y''+{\sin xy'+e^{-x}y=0}$ , then they can't have the same max and min.

My attempt, suppose they were, then $W(y_{1},y_{2})=y_{1}y_{2}'-y_{1}'y_{2}$.
now because it is min max  $y_{1}'=y_{2}'=0$ . so $W(y_{1},y_{2})=0$. which cannot be the case for independent  2nd order ODE's solutions.

hmmm something is fishy, we haven't used the ode at all.

2nd Attempt:
had they had the same min max point then again $W(y_1,y_2)=0$ but according to Abel's identity, this means $W(y_1,y_2)=e^{cos(x)}$ which cannot be zero, as cos is bounded and e is non zero for any real value.

Comment: The Wronskian may be zero even if the solutions are independent.

Comment: not for 2nd order ode @uniquesolution

Comment: @uniquesolution there is a special caveat which allows for the Wronskian to imply both directions if the functions are solutions to the same linear ODE

Comment: It's good you were suspicious of the first one. The Wronskian being $0$ at any one point doesn't mean anything, it's whether or not it's a zero function that matters.

Comment: The Wronskian for this DE is $$W= \exp \cos x $$

Comment: @Aryadeva thanks!

Comment: you're welcome ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are correct. If the Wronskian of two solutions of a second order linear ODE is zero at some point, then it is zero everywhere. Thus the solutions are linearly dependent.

Usually there is more emphasis on the contraposition, if the Wronskian is non-zero at one point, then it is non-zero everywhere.